# Mysql - Order By in IN Clausole

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple question.
I have to join multiple queries and most of them has ad IN clausole.
Unfortunally, MySQL doesn't allow ORDER BY in an UNION (only outside all unions) but I need a specific ordering that I can't get with an outside order by.

Question is: 
If I have a IN clausole like

```
foo in ('newyork','boston','atlanta')
```

may I assume MySql's engine will order the resulting rows by IN position (so, first all the row with foo = 'newyork' then 'boston' etc...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's nothing like that. You need to explicitly add an order by clause.

If you want to order your rows based on position in a set, you can use `field` function.

```
order by field(foo,'newyork','boston','atlanta')
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunally order by field is not usable inside Union but is a good solution. I will merge the queries outside in program code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *
from
(
  Select * from Temp1
  order by x
) Tbl1
UNION
Select *
from
(
  Select * from Temp2
  order by y
) Tbl2
```

Try this.